# How to resolve issue for previewing url in HTML5 video player when using live streaming via Azure?

Tags: azure, html5-video, live-streaming

I've faced an issue not showing preview when implement live streaming serviced by Azure.

I created a new live event and streaming endpoint in Azure.

[image]

[image]

But in frontend, when implement live streaming in Video player, it shows following error in previewing.

[image]

I logged response from network in inspect of Chrome.
It responses like the following:

```
<serverError>
  <status>404</status>
  <subStatus>1000</subStatus>
  <hresult>MPE_STORAGE_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND</hresult>
  <activityId>8000AEAC-0801-EC00-B63F-84710C7967BB</activityId>
  <serviceId>AAEBACDE-F9BE-44F5-8FE5-A55BB39AC182</serviceId>
</serverError>
```

Anyone can resolve this issue?

Comment: The real **error** is the red text in your bottom (last) picture. You don't have a valid link for the video player. In the first picture (top) what is the **"Streaming URL"** setting? Does it not mean the **viewing** link to your video?

Comment: In the first picture, it just shows RTMP input URL and output. It doesn't mean the preview link.

Comment: _"it just shows RTMP input URL"_ Yes because you must get it to generate your live stream video link. This usually means you get output of HLS (where an M3U8 file is the **src** in your HTML5 video player). Find out how then use in the player on web page.

Comment: How to get **src** for HTML5 video player from RTMP input URL?

Comment: I don't use Azure myself. I don't know what you can see. Read [this article until you understand](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-deliver-content-overview) the steps involved. From quick reading it seems you have (a) Bring some input (file, camera, RTMP link) then (b) Use the built-in [Dynamic Packager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/encode-dynamic-packaging-concept) to convert the stream into HLS (is usable with `<video>` tag) See section _"Delivering HLS"_ and further down see also _"On-demand streaming workflow"_.